# how to write compare function for Comparator

Tags: java, android

I have been looking through [several tutorials](http://www.journaldev.com/780/java-comparable-and-comparator-example-to-sort-objects) and they all seem to have a different algorithm on to write a compare function. Here are some examples:

```
public int compareTo(Fruit compareFruit) {

    int compareQuantity = ((Fruit) compareFruit).getQuantity(); 

    //ascending order
    return this.quantity - compareQuantity;

    //descending order
    //return compareQuantity - this.quantity;

}
```

[and](http://www.journaldev.com/780/java-comparable-and-comparator-example-to-sort-objects)

```
@Override
    public int compare(Employee e1, Employee e2) {
        return (int) (e1.getSalary() - e2.getSalary());
    }
```

is there a "wizard" which can automatically generate this ?

Comment: No wizard can figure out how _you_ want to compare things.

Comment: Equality of objects depends on your application requirement.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to take a look at the [Apache Commons Lang library](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/), which includes a CompareToBuilder class which can make building compareTo() a little easier.

http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-3.3.1/index.html